# build wine 32bit from source on ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Tags: 64-bit, wine, 12.04, 32-bit

I'm trying to build wine from source. 
apt-get build-dep wine installed some dependency packages. When running the configure script, following error occurs:

```
checking for X... no
configure: error: X 32-bit development files not found. Wine will be built
without X support, which probably isn't what you want. You will need
to install 32-bit development packages of Xlib/Xfree86 at the very least.
Use the --without-x option if you really want this.
```

Where can I find the 32bit development packages of Xlib/Xfree86 on 12.04 64bit?

Comment: not related to the question, but why not use the [wine ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa)?

Comment: i use wine quite often and sometimes new game releases won't work without patching wine. before wine 1.5.6, diablo 3 required patching and star wars the old republic still require custom patches.

Comment: @whitepixel Same problem with world of tanks. I'll be happy if somebody (or developers) create repository with fixed wine for games. ^.^

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/114460/how-to-install-lfreetype-using-wine

Answer (score 3):

To pass this error, you need to install X11 library development headers, for instance:

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev:i386
```

However when configuring wine, it won't solve the problem completely, as you'll get another error about [FreeType 32-bit development files not found](https://askubuntu.com/q/114460/78223) which would be more challenging (unless configuring `--without-freetype`).

So the easiest way is either to install wine binary package or build 32-bit wine on 64-bit machine using LXC (Linux Containers) as described in [here](http://wiki.winehq.org/BuildingBiarchWineOnUbuntu).

Comment: This did the trick for compiling: `sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev:i386 `

Answer (score 1):

You might need to compile wine yourself if you wanted to add custom patches. Currently for example the World of Warcraft and Diablo 3 Launchers/Downloaders depend on a patch that has not yet made it into the official wine repository.

Unfortunately ubuntu does either not ship the according 32-bit development files anymore or they currently cannot co-exist with its 64-bit pendant.

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine1.4/+bug/944321.

Comment: Does this bug still apply for Wine 1.7?

Answer (score 0):

I've been leveraging pdebuild which is a combination of [pbuilder](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PbuilderHowto) and [debuild](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/HandsOn) to build wine i386 on my laptop running Ubuntu 12.04 amd64.

I would first read through this page to understand what's going on and to setup your pbuilder environment: http://wiki.debian.org/PbuilderTricks

once you get things setup, you can pick the latest ppa and build from there:

```
$ dget -u -x http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wine1.5/wine1.5_1.5.9-0ubuntu2~pulse19.dsc
$ cd wine1.5-1.5.9
$ DIST=precise ARCH=i386 pdebuild
```

You can place patches in the wine1.5-1.5.9/debian/patches directory and add in the file into the wine1.5-1.5.9/debian/patches/series file and also run dch -i to increment the version number on the package before running the pdebuild command to apply your own patches.

You could probably just use pbuilder and build wine from trunk as well, but I like to build from deb packages whenever I can.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the only way is to use chrooted environment:
http://wiki.winehq.org/WineOn64bit

Answer (score -1):

You can download the source code using `apt-get source wine1.*`. Then `cd` to the folder, apply packages, and use `dpgk` to pack everything up again, which makes it compile as well. Then you turn it into a `.deb` and install.

Something like this:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep wine1.3
apt-get source wine1.3
cd wine1.3-*
patch -p1 < foo.patch
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i wine1.3*.deb
```